# Who could help me to add a correct Autoplay Wallop slider

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I've added an autoplay function to the Wallop slider and I'm trying to add a restart after the user clicks on his keyboard on the left or right arrow. Problem, if you click more than once on one of the arrow, the slide goes weird ^^

Here is a pen of my work : http://codepen.io/Le-future/pen/Nxexrw

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";

    var wallopEl = document.querySelector('.Wallop');
      var slider = new Wallop(wallopEl);

  var timer = setInterval('$(".Wallop .Wallop-buttonNext").click()', 5000); //assign timer to a variable


    $(document).keydown( function(eventObject) {

        if(eventObject.which==37) {//left arrow

            $('.Wallop .Wallop-buttonPrevious').click();//emulates click on prev button 

            clearInterval(timer); //clear interval

            setTimeout(function() {

                var timer = setInterval('$(".Wallop .Wallop-buttonNext").click()', 5000); //start it again

            }, 8000);

        } 

        else if(eventObject.which==39) {//right arrow

            $('.Wallop .Wallop-buttonNext').click();//emulates click on next button

            clearInterval(timer); //clear interval

            setTimeout(function() {

                var timer = setInterval('$(".Wallop .Wallop-buttonNext").click()', 5000); //start it again

            }, 8000);

        }

    });

});
```

Don't hesitate to press more than twice the arrow of your keyboard to see the problem.

Thanks by advance for any help :-)

Comment: Nobody can help me? ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this code sample from the repo:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var photoslider = new WallopSlider('.photo-slider');

    var count = photoslider.allItemsArrayLength;
    var start = photoslider.currentItemIndex;
    var end = count+1;
    var index = start;    

    jQuery(function(){
        setInterval(function() {
            photoslider.goTo(index);     
            ++index;
            if (index == end) {index=start}
        },3000);
    });
});
```

Source: 
[peduarte/wallop issues](https://github.com/peduarte/wallop/issues/13)

Also check out http://codepen.io/peduarte/pen/wKwbYJ
and http://codepen.io/peduarte/pen/RapQBB